# Creating and disposing SecretClient

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-keyvault

How do I create and dispose of SecretClient from `Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets`? I'm migrating from `KeyVaultClient` and can't seem to find much documentation on this.

Answer (score 2):

There is a really good article explaining how Azure SDK's clients work - [Lifetime management for Azure SDK .NET clients](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sdk/lifetime-management-and-thread-safety-guarantees-of-azure-sdk-net-clients/):

> - **Client lifetime**: The main rule of Azure SDK client lifetime management is: **treat clients as singletons**.
> - **Thread-safety**: Clients are thread-safe. Models are not thread-safe.
> - Clients are immutable
> - **Clients are not disposable: Shared HttpClient as default**: One question that comes up often is why aren’t HTTP-based Azure clients implementing `IDisposable` while internally using an `HttpClient` that is disposable? All Azure SDK clients, by default, use a single shared `HttpClient` instance and don’t create any other resources that need to be actively freed. The shared client instance persists throughout the entire application lifetime.

From [Azure Key Vault secret client library for .NET](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/main/sdk/keyvault/Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets#azure-key-vault-secret-client-library-for-net), there are lots of samples on how to use the new clients:

```cs
// Create a new secret client using the default credential from Azure.Identity using environment variables previously set,
// including AZURE_CLIENT_ID, AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET, and AZURE_TENANT_ID.
var client = new SecretClient(vaultUri: new Uri(vaultUrl), credential: new DefaultAzureCredential());

// Create a new secret using the secret client.
KeyVaultSecret secret = client.SetSecret("secret-name", "secret-value");

// Retrieve a secret using the secret client.
secret = client.GetSecret("secret-name");
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the use case of an application, a SecretClient  offers both ***synchronous and asynchronous*** activities. You can interact with secrets in Azure Key Vault once a SecretClient has been initialised.

***Creating secret :***

```
KeyVaultSecret secret = client.SetSecret("secret-name", "secret-value");

Console.WriteLine(secret.Name);
Console.WriteLine(secret.Value);
Console.WriteLine(secret.Properties.Version);
Console.WriteLine(secret.Properties.Enabled);
```

***StartDeleteSecret to delete a secret stored in the Azure Key Vault. When [soft-delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/key-vault/general/soft-delete-overview) is not enabled for the Azure Key Vault permanently disposes the secret***.

```
DeleteSecretOperation operation = client.StartDeleteSecret("secret-name");

DeletedSecret secret = operation.Value;
Console.WriteLine(secret.Name);
Console.WriteLine(secret.Value);
```

For more information in detail, please **refer** below links:

[Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets/)

[Azure](https://github.com/Azure)/**[azure-sdk-for-net](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net)**